# PhpRedis with Laravel 6 - alias colission using Forge

Tags: php, laravel, forge, phpredis

I'm currently struggling with setting my redis queue right on prod server. 
I have:

1. set DigitalOcean droplet using Forge
2. turned redis on
3. completely deleted alias for Redis in `config/app.php`
4. used `php artisan cache:clear` and `config:clear`
5. deleted `bootstrap/cache/services.php` file

But I'm still getting this error:
[image]

On local developement I've used database driver, and I have not changed anything in redis config itself, since it was set to `phpredis` by default.

Any piece of advice will be veeery helpful! Thanks guys.

Comment: Did you clear any config caches? (e.g. `php artisan config:clear` ) If this doesn't work (likely) then you might need to delete it manually from the bootstrap folder.

Comment: @apokryfos yes, forgot to add that. Used `config:clear` and `cache:clear`. I've deleted `bootstrap/cache/services.php` as you adviced, still not working :(

Comment: @NorbertJurga were you able to fix this?

Comment: @AmirAsyraf, didn't have time for that, created new droplet and everything was ok this time :)